# symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: _alloca

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, alloca

I'm building a shared object (.so) that internally makes use of a function _alloca() (defined in malloc.h). This .so compiles smoothly. But as soon as I call a function that makes use of _alloca(), my application crashes whith a console output

```
symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: _alloca
```

So: any idea against what library I have to link during build to get this external reference resolved?

Platform is CentOS7 x64

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using _alloca instead of alloca?  What is the advantage of the  underbar version?

Answer (score 2):

`_alloca` is used by the Visual C++ compiler on Windows. You need to use `alloca` (without the underscore) for compiling on Linux.